# Change tableviewHeader on didSelect of UIcollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have 2 ViewControllers, `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`.
First one contains `UITableView` and the other contains `UICollectionView` with headerViews respectively.

And suppose I have 2 `UITableView` headers, DefaultHeaderView and SelectedHeaderView, so what am I trying to achieve?

what I am trying to achieve is that when the `UICollectionView` in the `SecondViewController` `didSelect` is tapped, I want the `FirstViewController`'s `UITableView` to change/replace its `DefaultHeaderView` with the `SelectedHeaderView`
.
But, what I have tried so far seems to be not working or is not the correct approach at all.

I have declared this variable in `FirstViewController` to determine if the change is needed and to reload the tableView:

```
var isNewHeader = false {
        didSet {
            tableVIew.reloadData()
        }
```

and Here is my `tableView` `viewForHeaderInSection` method:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let defaultHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: DefaultHeaderView.identifier) as! DefaultHeaderView
        let selectedHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: SelectedHeaderView.identifier) as! SelectedHeaderView

        if (isNewHeader) {
            return selectedHeader
        } else {
            // defaultHeader is set as the default value.
            return defaultHeader
        }
        
    }
```

and after it has been created, inside the `SecondViewController`'s `UICollectionView`s `didSelectItem` method I am trying to set the `isNewHeader` to `true` and get the `FirstViewController` to return the replaced headerView.

```
extension SecondViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController") as? FirstViewController {
            //** Here, I am getting `nil` return value for tableView in `FirstViewController` 
                 which actually is obvious.
            vc.isNewHeader = true
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any better way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`instantiateViewController` creates the view controller with the specified identifier and initializes it with the data from the storyboard. You can simply check it by comparing instances

As you're using `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` I assume that the `FirstViewController` is the root of `navigationController`

You can use something like `if let vc = navigationController?.viewControllers.first as? FirstViewController`

Comment: thanks for your answer, however your answer is far away from the question context.. .

Comment: why so? you have the `first VC` which has the `table` inside and presents the second one by pushing/presenting/whatever. As I see in `didSelect` method you're trying to get the instance of the `first VC` and update the property. But you're using `instantiateViewController` method which is incorrect. I assumed that you have both in a navigation stack if not just replace `navigationController?.viewControllers.first as? FirstViewController` with `whatever.viewControllers.first as? FirstViewController`

Comment: It worked.. i had my own misconfiguration too, so it did not work at first but it works.. .